# Mostrar div com imagem ampliada ao passar mouse em thumbnail

Tags: javascript, css

Tenho uma div onde são mostradas as thumbnails ( miniaturas) das imagens e outra div acima com o texto, ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer para que ao passar o mouse na thumbnail (efeito hover normal) surja uma div maior que sobreponha o texto e mostre a imagem da thumbnail maior ( que seria o tamanho normal) e ao tirar o mouse da thumbnail a div se oculte normalmente, ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer isso?

O HTML seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
    <div id="content">

<div id="images-normal">
<img src="#" id="normal-01" />
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum .... </p>

<div id="images-thumb">
<img src="#" id="thumb-01" />
</div>

</div><!--content-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes fazer isso só com CSS.

Por exemplo com este HTML:

```
<div class="post">
  <div class="texto">Bla bla bla</div>
  <div class="thumb"><img src="/img/logo.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="imagem"><img src="/img/logo.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

precisas de usar o selector `+` que seleciona o próximo elemento assim:

```
.thumb:hover + div.imagem {
  display: block;
}
```

e dessa maneira quando o `.thumb` receber `hover` então o estilo  `display: block;` é aplicado a `div.imagem`.

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vznkdhsy/

Também podes usar `opacity` em vez de `display` assim: http://jsfiddle.net/vznkdhsy/1/

Comment: E se forem várias imagens e a div thumb não for "filha" da div maior?

Comment: @NGTHM4R3 é dificil responder em detalhe a todos os cenários. Mas mostra o teu HTML e adapto a resposta.

Comment: Ok, vou atualizar a pergunta

Comment: A div "images-normal" é a div que irá aparecer no efeito hover e sobrepor o texto que e quando tirar o mouse ela some tbm, essa div maior já teria um tamanho definido e o texto tbm pra não ficar desproporcional, entende...

Comment: @NGTHM4R3 nesse caso vai ser preciso JavaScript. Usas jQuery? ou preferes nativo?

Comment: Oque você achar melhor está bom, eu tenho preferencia em CSS porque eu entendo um pouco, entende...

Comment: E Então, conseguiu?

Comment: @NGTHM4R3 tinha esquecido, lamento. Uma duvida no teu HTML usas IDs. Vai haver mais HTML como esse ou é só uma imagem/thumb por página?

Comment: Vão ter várias imagens...